# Image in Email Subject using PHP

Tags: html-email

I want to add image like company logo in email subject using php mail function i have added

```
$subject = "<img src=\"https://www.donndraper.com/images/logo.png\" width=\"50px\">"); 
$header = "From: $email\n Content-Type: text/HTML;";
```

Comment: Have you EVER seen an image in an email subject?

Comment: The OP is not totally crazy. Just got an email from AT&T that had this subject (show original, gmail) `Subject: =?UTF-8?B?VGFsay4gQ29ubmVjdC4gUmVsYXguIOKYug==?=` the result is a smiley at the end of the subject. On my iPhone it was a pretty yellow image smiley, but I think that's just the iPhone replacing a symbol with an image to make things look prettier.

Answer (score 3):

What JerrySeeger was trying to say, in a fairly condescending manner, is that e-mail does not support images in the subject.

The SMTP protocol was designed 20 years before HTML was even invented.

What you desire is simply not possible.

Comment: "The SMTP protocol was designed 20 years before HTML was even invented"--and yet HTML mail *bodies* are everywhere...

Comment: @MattGibson The issue is that no e-mail client that exists, has ever existed, or will ever exist, support rendering an image in the `Subject`. Which makes the answer to Khalid's question: *Not possible*.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot include custom images (such as your company logo), however, there are a limited number of Unicode images that you can use in the header.

Some clients render them by using color images rather than treat them as characters in a font. The following article has a few images comparing how various mobile devices render them:

- [Symbols in Subject Lines: How to Get Your Email Noticed](http://bronto.com/blog/email-marketing-strategy/symbols-subject-lines-how-get-your-email-noticed#.UhEB79KmiSo)

And you can see Wikipedia for a long list of the available characters, and if for some reason your font does not support those characters, the second link are bitmap renders of those characters:

- [Wikipedia: Miscellaneous Symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miscellaneous_Symbols)
- [Online Uniode Character Map](http://www.unipad.org/unimap/index.php?param_char=&param_block=Miscellaneous+Symbols)

Answer (score 0):

@GUS well said.. and you guys are all wrong.

You may use any unicode utf-8 or Base64 in mail subject and latest Trend in mass Mailers. 
its pretty easy to implement .