# Adding Icon to Cakephp Email Subject

Tags: cakephp-3.0, cakeemail

Please how can i add icon/ company logo to the subject line of my email so that recipients can also see my logo alongside with the subject line of my mail as being practiced by most corporate organizations. I use cakephp 3

Answer (score 0):

To add custom logo, there is no way. Only some emojy codes are exeption. SMTP protocol is older than HTML. So it's not cakephp or PHP  related, but SMTP itself. You can learn more in here. [Image in Email Subject using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17087660/image-in-email-subject-using-php)